# How to transfer char to string in c#

Tags: c#, foreach

The output is:

```
'6' '+' '1' '2' '*' '2'
```

But I want to get output as

```
'6' '12' '*' '2'
```

[image]

Comment: foreach(char i in formula)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Do that like this:

```
string formula = "6+12*2";
foreach (char chr in formula)
{
    Console.WriteLine(chr);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the output is '6' '+' '1' '2' '*' '2'. however i want to get it is '6' '+' '12' '*' '2'

Comment: @L.Wen - Why have you accepted this answer? It is clearly wrong.

Comment: firstly check the question edit man  first he want to print only after spliting